# Forwarding All Traffic from Global External IP to a Domain on GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have an Autopilot GKE cluster set up. There is an Ingress which is an entry point to the app deployed in the cluster. I managed to configure SSL and HTTP -> HTTPS redirection with ease.

I also configured Cloud DNS that resolves my domain name to the cluster's IP (global static IP, let's name it `global-front-app-ip`).

This works without any problems. I'm able to access the app with the domain I own. My setup is very simillar to [the one described in this article](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip).

What I'm trying to achieve now is to redirect all the clients that try to access the app with LB IP `global-front-app-ip` to the domain name (`http://global-front-app-ip` -> `http://my-domain.com`).

I played with LB forwarding rules and Cloud Armor but I haven't found a working solution.

Comment: That's not possible with Ingress. Does your certificate support both the domain and IP at alternateDNS ?

Comment: The certificate I got supports the domain only. When accessing the site via IP, I got a notification about an unsecured connection.

Comment: That's expected, the certificate will only work when trying to reach the LB via the domain configured in the certificate. You should re-create the certificate to add the IP address as well. But in all cases you will not be able to redirect from the IP to the domain i'm afraid.

Comment: Hello, Where is allocated your DNS records? Is there any specific reason to reroute your clients from your working http-to-https? Could you describe what are you trying to deploy? Maybe there is another best option for your project.

Comment: The DNS I use is Cloud DNS running within GCP. My main idea is to ensure that my application is accessible only via the domain name. An idea that just has hit my mind is to try to edit DNS A record with a private IP (accessible within the same VPC). Then I wouldn't need to expose the public IP of my LB. I would need to check if that's doable :)

Comment: What about use NAT?